# How to write this query in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a requirement to insert more than one record into the table where the stored procedure will return the value for insertion. Please consider my logic.

**Query Logic**

```
foreach(var a in (select id from table1))
{
  insert into table2 values(a,DateTime.Now)
}
```

I need the same above logic needs to be done in SQL server. Any help to this solution will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: `insert into table2(idColumn, dateColumn) select id, getdate() from table1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and working well. Thanks to @Nikola Markovinović

```
insert into table2(idColumn, dateColumn) select id, getdate() from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @a int=0
while(@a<10)
begin
if(@a in (select id from table1))
begin
  insert into table2 values(a,DateTime.Now)
  set @a=@a+1
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps..

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=5)
BEGIN
PRINT @intFlag
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
IF @intFlag = 4
BREAK;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a int = 0, @n int, @i int = 1

select @n=COUNT(*) from table1 

while @i < @n
begin
insert into table2 values 
select x.a,Getdate() from 
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [key]) as slno,* from table1 ) as x where  x.slno  = @i
set @i=@i+1;
end
```